# iOS Swift Mapkit annotations order

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit

I need to keep an order for the annotations. I use custom annotationViews.

Each annotations are related to a point of interest, from 1 to n, so I need to open POI 1 when the map open the first time and then, when I click next or previous, I need to open POI 2 etc..
I keep an index to show in the detail callout the Point 1. I know that annotations are a Set, not an array.
Thanks

```swift
tour.poi?.forEach {
    let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees($0.lat), CLLocationDegrees($0.long))
    let poiAnnotation = PoiAnnotation(coord: coord, poi: $0, index: index)
    map.addAnnotation(poiAnnotation)
    index = index + 1
}
```

My ugly solution :

```swift
let annotation = map.annotations.first { $0.subtitle == String(poiIndex) }
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
   self.map.setCenter(annotation!.coordinate, animated: false)
}completion: { (_) in
   self.map.selectAnnotation(annotation!, animated: true)
}
```

I've added some animation to always center the pin before opening the callout.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I know that annotations are a Set, not an array.

That is incorrect.

The map view `annotations` property is an array, not a set. To quote the docs:

> annotations
>
> The complete list of annotations associated with the receiver.
>
> var annotations: [MKAnnotation] { get }

Note the type of `annotations`: `[MKAnnotation]`. That's an array.

You should be able to keep an instance variable with the index of the annotation you have displayed most recently, and increment it when you display the map again.

If you're opening and closing a map view over and over with the same set of annotations you might want to keep your array of annotations rather than rebuilding it each time. For that matter you might want to hide the map view rather than closing it, and then simply show it again. Map views use a **lot** of network data to display.

Comment: You're right, I looked just below and saw @available(iOS 4.2, *)
    open func annotations(in mapRect: MKMapRect) -> Set<AnyHashable>. But the if I open annotations[0], never the same that's opening. I don't reopen the map, just the annotations one after the other. thanks

Comment: The function `annotations(in mapRect: MKMapRect) -> Set<AnyHashable>` is different. That lets you find the annotations that fall within a given `MKMapRect`. That function returns a subset of the annotations in the map (as a `Set`, as you have observed.) You usually use the function to find the annotations that are currently visible in the map region. If you want to use that function you will need a way to preserve the order of your annotations. (Map annotations (MKAnnotation) are a protocol. You could add an index value to yours, and after calling `annotations(in:)`, sort the result by index.